# How to check double relation in Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

That's a very newbie question, but I have spent lot of time trying to figure it out.

Check my DB structure:

```
Users:
id, user_name, ...

Smokes:
id, latitude, longitude, ...

Lights:
id, user_id, smoke_id, ... 

Users has_many Lights
Smokes has_many Lights
Lights belongs_to Users
Lights belongs_to Smokes
```

I need to know if a User has a Light in determined Smoke.

Something like this:

```
  # User model... (user.rb)
  def lighted?(smoke_id)
    # Return true if User lighted the smoke.
    smoke = Smoke.find_by_id(smoke_id)
    return true if self.lights << smoke
  end
```

Comment: Quick tip, and more guidance than anything. What does Smoke.find_by_id(smoke_id) give you in the rails console (rails c)

Answer (score 0):

```
def lighted?(smoke_id)
    # Return true if User lighted the smoke.
    smoke = Smoke.find(smoke_id)
    smoke.lights.collect(&:user_id).include?(self.id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a an alternative approach for a direct answer:

```
def lighted?(smoke_id)
  Light.exists?("smoke_id = ? and user_id = ?", smoke_id, self.id)
end
```